# C++: boost ptree remove children: no matching function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-propertytree

In an attempt to remove children of a boost property tree, I use a direct node in `erase` function which lead to

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::erase(std::pair<const 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 
boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)’
```

at

```
pt0.erase(pt_child);
```

What is the correct form of the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

void print(const ptree &p)
{
    json_parser::write_json(std::cout, p);
}

int main()
{
    ptree pt0;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        pt0.put_child("kid"+std::to_string(i+1),ptree());
    print(pt0);

    for(auto& pt_child : pt0)
        pt0.erase(pt_child);
    print(pt0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post entire error message.

Comment: @yurikilochek, ok.

Comment: off topic: you can just `write_json(std::cout, p)` no need to pass it through stringstream.

Comment: @yurikilochek, updated. thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html) you can only `.erase` by `key_type` or by `iterator`, but you are trying to do it by `value_type`.

You can do either do

```
for(auto& [key, data]: pt0)
    pt0.erase(key);
```

or loop over iterators explicitly:

```
for(auto it = pt0.begin(); it != pt0.end(); ++it)
    pt0.erase(it);
```

But since you are removing all children anyway, a better way would be to just

```
pt0.clear();
```

Comment: @ar2015 why don't you [read the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp683462128-bb) yourself?

Comment: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token ` for(auto& [key, data]: pt0)`, error: ‘key’ was not declared in this scope, error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @ar2015 this is c++17 syntax, until then you can do `for(auto& pt_child: pt0) pt0.erase(pt_child.first);`

Comment: Both loops modify the container during modification. That's UB. You must write the loops safely like: `for(auto it = pt0.begin(); it != pt0.end();) { it = pt0.erase(it); }`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:ptree.get_child("path.to").erase("child"); Note that this deletes ALL nodes named "child" within the path "path.to" and their subchildren.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate but the `ptree` api doesn't have a `remove_child` method that works with a `property_tree::path` just like it does for `get_child`. Here's a small method that does that though. The important part is that you can use the dot notation to specify whatever subchild you want to remove. Also this implementation only removes a single child.

```cpp
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

// TODO: this should support boost::property_tree::path
// like get_child does to make it obvious that it supports
// the path separator notation for specifying sub children
bool remove_child(boost::property_tree::ptree& pt, const std::string& path) {
  // split up the path into each sub part
  std::vector<std::string> path_parts;
  boost::split(path_parts, path, boost::is_any_of("."));

  // check each part of the path
  auto* root = &pt;
  for (const auto& part : path_parts) {
    // if we dont have this sub child bail
    auto found = root->find(part);
    if (found == root->not_found())
      return false;

    // if this was the last one to look for remove it
    if (&part == &path_parts.back()) {
      root->erase(root->to_iterator(found));
    }// next sub child
    else {
      root = &found->second;
    }
  }

  // made it to the last sub child without bailing on not found
  return true;
}
```